# python crypt.crypt in ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

hi i need this code in ruby I don't know how I write the crypt.crypt method in ruby, any ideas?

(I want to simulate the linux comand .htpasswd)

```
import random
import crypt

letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' \
          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' \
          '0123456789/.'
salt = random.choice(letters) + random.choice(letters)

password = "bla"

print crypt.crypt(password, salt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Ruby's [String#crypt](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000808) is equivalent to Python's crypt.crypt, so the Ruby equivalent to your code would be something like:

```
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/.'
salt = letters[rand letters.length].chr + letters[rand letters.length].chr

password = "bla"

puts password.crypt(salt)
```

Answer (score 3):

Jordan already told you about String#crypt, so I'll just show you an easier way to create your letters array:

```
letters = [*'a'..'z'] + [*'A'..'Z'] + [*0..9] + %w(/ .)
```

**Update:** since this got upvoted after more than 2 years, I might as well add the 1.9 way of doing this (using multiple splats and character literals):

```
letters = [*?a..?z, *?A..?Z, *0..9, ?/, ?.]
```

Comment: And then use something like: `salt = letters.sample(2).join` to get two random letters from the array. Nice.